# How can I manually restore the bootmgr on Windows Small Business Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, bootmgr

The bootmgr was deleted on or Dell T310 running Windows Server 2008 as a result of bad partitioning. How can manually I restore  the bootmgr?

Comment: If you have the install disc `bootrec /fixboot` should resolve it

Answer (score 1):

Using a console running from the install CD do as follows:

> bootrec /fixboot

**This will attempt to rebuild your current bootloader. if it fails, use the steps below.**

```
c:
cd boot
bootsect /nt60 c: /force /mbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

**NOTE**: After using the "bootrec /rebuldbcd" command, you will be prompted to accept a Windows installation. Accept the installation, then wait for the process to finish. Once it's done, reboot your computer and you should have a boot loader ready to go.

---

**If rebuilding the mbr and bcd still does not work**

A startup repair is likely needed to be done. Follow the steps below to perform a startup repair.

1. Insert the Windows 2008 installation CD/DVD into the recovered system's DVD-ROM and restart the system.
2. Select to boot from the Windows installation CD/DVD when prompted.
3. From the menu options displayed, choose the repair option and then open a command prompt option.
4. At the command prompt, type the following commands pressing the Enter key after each line:

> ```
> cd recovery
> run startrep.exe
> ```

[full credits](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH126257)

Comment: Thank you for the definitive response, the install disk boots me directly into the Windows server installation options. This could be as a result of the partition being deleted.